# Safari showing HTML5 video controls and playing audio, but not showing video?

Tags: html, video, safari

Safari 5.1.7 on XP was displaying HTML5 video yesterday. Today it only displays audio and the controls. I refuse to believe Safari has a mind of its own displaying elements on random.

For the reference, website URL is: `http://onelove-themovie.co.uk/`

```
<div id="trailer">
<img id="close" src="images/close.png" alt="close" />
<div id="video">
<video controls  autoplay="autoplay" poster="video/trailer.jpg" width="600"         onclick="if(/Android/.test(navigator.userAgent))this.play();">
<source src="video/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="video/trailer.webm" type="video/webm" />
<source src="video/trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
<embed src="video/flashfox.swf" width="600" height="480" flashVars="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;loop=true&amp;src=trailer.mp4"  allowFullScreen="true" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_en" />
</video>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works for me on Win7 and Safari 5.1.7...

Comment: Is it just breaking on this site or all all sites broken for you on your XP machine? Is this working? http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html